# Laravel How can I configure "reserved_at" in the jobs table

Tags: laravel

I want to use `Carbon::today()->addMonth()` as default value of `reserved_at` column in jobs table
then I will use ite in the job in the way of

> ```
>     if(reserved_at == Carbon->today())
>       { 
>           //execution
>       } else {
>           //don't
>       }
> ```

Comment: Do you want to add the default current date in reserved_at column ?? @Amine Merjri

Comment: please describe more

Answer (score 0):

You can set `reserved_at` in model's `creating` event within the model `boot()` method, like that add following method in `Job` model:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->reserved_at = Carbon::today()->addMonth();
        });
    }
```

It will append `reserved_at` field `value` in model when you storing data using `eloquent` methods.

> **Note:** It'll not work with `insert()` query builder method.

Comment: thank you but this is not what I really want 
I wanted it to be automatic and I figured it out 
it's by using the function of the class InteractsWithQueue          
`->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5))`  with the dispatch function

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it's by using the function of the class InteractsWithQueue
`->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5))` with the dispatch function